# how to get related topic from the database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a blog and articles on my website and tried to compare present topic from the records/topics in the database.

Just like what I see on most websites, I want to display RELATED or SIMILAR topics from the database and display it on my website.

```
 //On my query, I used :
   $topic = "How to know your strengths";
   $sql   = "SELECT * FROM articlestbl WHERE articles like '%s$topic%'";
```

Now, I want to display more topics related to this, but it only displays 
topics which starts and ends with $str.

Does anybody knows?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM articlestbl WHERE articles like '%".$topic."%'";
```

Comment: Yes, but I should not use that query. I need to display RELATED topics even if string does not show using like %$topic%

Comment: Possibly you should need to link your related topics with each other topics like if you have topic named: `adam's stories` and you know blah blah 4 other stories are related to it, then you should consider them linking with that one topic by assigning same category to them. Without that this is not possible either.

Comment: Just like how stackoverflow does, .. On the right panel of this page, shows List of Related topics..

Comment: fine, the reason is that they are linked to `PHP` tag [SO PHP Tagged Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) so it consider them as **Related** Means there is linking of posted question with tag `PHP`. Moreover, they are too working on same hierarchy. **Keyword** based linking.